# How to specify dozer.properties location?

Tags: spring, configuration, dozer

I'm using Dozer with Spring 3.0.x. Here is my mapper bean definition:

```
<bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="mappingFiles">
        <list>
            <value>dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to put dozer.properties file in src/main/resources/conf/app/dozer.properties.

How can I specify the custom dozer.properties location?

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="org.dozer.Mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
  <property name="mappingFiles">
    <list>
      <value>dozer-global-configuration.xml</value>
      <value>dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Make sure you xml file is on the classpath

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/springintegration.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/configuration/configuration.html):

> An alternative Dozer properties file
>   can be specified via the
>   dozer.configuration system property.
>   ex)
>   `-Ddozer.configuration=someDozerConfigurationFile.properties`

So just launch your app with `-Ddozer.configuration=/conf/app/dozer.properties`

Comment: Yes, I read that section of the docs, but I have lot of balanced servers so I'd prefer to include that config inside the .war